# TF400018: The local version table for the local workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

> ```
> TF400018: The local version table for the local workspace WEBSERVER; 
> (My name was here) could not be opened. Access is denied
> ```

I keep getting the error above as soon as I open Visual Studio. I cannot access any of my projects.  I am the administrator on TFS and I can also access TFS via the web client so I don't see how it could be an access problem.  Has anyone gotten this before? I have seen similar errors posted but not the same one.

Comment: The local version table is a file on your local disk, inside a directory called `$tf` at the top level of one of your local working folder mappings.  This message indicates that you have a permission problem reading or writing that file.  Did you run VS as an administrator at some point and are now running as a normal user account?

Comment: no not to my knowledge. I ran it just now as administrator and i got the same error. Is there anything i can delete in that folder that is considered cache.

Comment: I have multiple projects mapped to this machine

Comment: For me I resolved it as follows: 1.) Close VS 2.) checked if there was any other instance of VS running(using task manager) and as expected there was one. 3.) killed this rogue vs process 4.) restarted VS. and it worked

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I fixed this by renaming the $tf hidden folder in our working directory

Comment: I did this and suddenly I had 3 million new and untracked changes.

Comment: For me I resolved it as follows: 1.) Close VS 2.) checked if there was any other instance of VS running(using task manager) and as expected there was one. 3.) killed this rogue vs process 4.) restarted VS. and it worked

Comment: After doing this; right-clicking the solution and selecting Get Latest Version(recursive) allowed me to work on changes again

Answer (score 6):

I had pending changes, so to play it safe, here's what I did;

- back up your source directory. Since you can't connect to TFS, you can't shelve or similar, so make sure you've got a copy before trying anything.
- rename `$tf` to, say `__$tf`. After this, TFS can't track the differences between your local disk and remote
- get latest source code (I used tf.exe for this). All your pending changes now show up as merge conflicts.
- open visual studio, and in "Pending Changes", choose "Actions | Resolve Conflicts (21)"
- In the Resolve Conflicts window, choose 'Keep Local File Contents' for every file. You can ctrl+a to select all and then choose 'Keep Local File Contents' to do them all in a single shot.
- If you've added any files, you'll need to add them back to source control - right-click in Solution Explorer and "Add file to source control"
- When you check in, be careful of any changes colleagues might have made to the file you're editing.

Comment: This is really annoying. I'm plagued with this error. Just last week I renamed the folder and had to manualy resolve conflicts, hundreds of them, one at a time. I wasn't even allowed to multi-select and use same for all. Now it's back!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issues by deleting/ unbinding all workspaces in my TFS. after that i was able to reopen my projects without errors.  I rebound them back in the change source control menu.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by :

1. Backup your local files
2. delete your cache C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation{version}\Cache
3. From file menu, source control, advanced, workspaces, then remove your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by:

1.) Rename my Local Path (to which TFS was pointing to).

2.) Start Visual Studio 2019 > Source Code Explorer.

It complained it no longer had a Local Path--I pointed it to a new location of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error using the VS Source Control Explorer to download projects from Azure TFS. My company had recently moved from on-prem TFS into the cloud.

Update: I think the problem turned out to be that my local workspace was just too large. It seems likely that the background process responsible for keeping local files in sync with the cloud was working so hard that it caused errors when any attempt was made to pull down or sync a project.

To make it worse, even after unmapping the local workspace in TFS and rebooting the machine, the workspace folder was locked and could not be renamed.

In the end I just created a new folder, mapped it as my workspace in TFS, copied over just the projects I needed from my old workspace, and the errors finally stopped.